# Flutter: How to put a horizontal scrollbar of the Listview to be at the middle of the list?

Tags: flutter

I was able to implement the scrollable horizontal list view in flutter. But I need to put the scrollbar to be at the middle of the List. Right now is at the left which is the starting point of my list.

here is my current scrollable listview

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
  // padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 24.0),
  margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.25,
  child: Scrollbar(
  isAlwaysShown: true,
  controller: _scrowllController,
  thickness: 3.0,
  child: ListView.builder(
    controller: _scrowllController,
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    itemCount: numbers.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4,
        child: Card(
          color: Colors.blue,
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom:30.0, right: 10.0),
          child: Container(
            child: Center(
                child: Text(
              numbers[index].toString(),
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 36.0),
            )),
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
  ),
);
```

}

here is what the code above showing
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQp5z.jpg)

And this is what i want to be shown when you first open the app
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQD2H.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Set the initialScrollOffset of your scrollController to be `numbers.length / 2 * itemWidth`

Also since your items are all the same width I recommend setting the `itemExtent` of the ListView since that has a big impact on performance

Comment: Thanks for reply. But how to get numbers and itemWidth you mentioned in your reply. Sorry am a new in flutter